# Unable to install bson_ext 1.8.2 gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bson, bson-ext

I am unable to install the bson_ext 1.8.2 gem in my mongo project directory.
In specific I tried running `bundle install` and `gem install bson_ext -v '1.8.2'`

I tried other solutions present on the forum but in vain.

```
Installing bson_ext (1.8.2) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/jayanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for asprintf()... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for ruby/regex.h... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling bson_buffer.c
compiling encoding_helpers.c
compiling cbson.c
cbson.c: In function ‘write_utf8’:
cbson.c:118:36: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘check_string’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from cbson.c:66:0:
encoding_helpers.h:26:10: note: expected ‘const unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
cbson.c: In function ‘write_element’:
cbson.c:301:20: warning: unused variable ‘values’ [-Wunused-variable]
cbson.c: In function ‘objectid_generate’:
cbson.c:936:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘htonl’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
cbson.c:944:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘htons’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
cbson.c: In function ‘write_element’:
cbson.c:316:17: warning: ignoring return value of ‘asprintf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
linking shared-object bson_ext/cbson.so

make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 cbson.so /home/jayanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mongo-tools/gems/bson_ext-1.8.2/ext/bson_ext/bson_ext
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/home/jayanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mongo-tools/gems/bson_ext-1.8.2/ext/bson_ext/bson_ext': No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/jayanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mongo-tools/gems/bson_ext-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/jayanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mongo-tools/gems/bson_ext-1.8.2/ext/cbson/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bson_ext (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bson_ext -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

gem install bson_ext -v '1.8.2 fails with the same error.

The solution here(https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-551?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)  says its fixed....but i still face the same

Comment: not working for me any answer

Answer (score 5):

Try updating rubygems and then installing bson_ext.

```
gem update --system
gem install bson_ext
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ruby 2.0.0p0

When I installed bson-1.9.2.gem I got this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing bson_ext:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/albert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

The following worked for me:

```
gem update --system
gem install bson_ext
```